# Demo email sending and receiving locally using a mail server

Tags: email, windows-server-2003

I have a upcoming demo of a product that (amongst other things) sends email alerts. I don't know if I'll have an Internet connection for this demo. I also need to be able to fire up something like Outlook Express and view these alerts.

So I have come to the conclusion that I need to install some sort of small mail server to send the mail and that I can then connect a mail client to.

Are there any tiny mail servers out there that will install on a windows 2003 server? I really need to smallest and thinnest possible as I got 100 other stuff running on the same development machine and I don't want to slow it down ever further ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the free version of Smarter Mail http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterMail/Free-Windows-Mail-Server.aspx

It's a full blown exchange equivalent mail server which is limited to 1 domain and 10 mailboxes, never installed it myself (only ever been an end user) so don't know how 'tiny' an install it is